# Angular filter array inside array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I'm working in an Angular 9 app and I need to filter an array based on another array inside each object. To understand me here is an example of the array

```
const products = [
  {
      name: 'Product 1',
      origins: [
          { quantity: 1, name: 'Pack 1' },
          { quantity: 1, name: 'Pack 2' },
      ]
  },
  {
      name: 'Product 2',
      origins: [
          { quantity: 1, name: 'Pack 1' },
          { quantity: 1, name: 'Pack 2' },
      ]
  },
  {
     name: 'Product 3',
     origins: [
          { quantity: 1, name: 'Inventory' },
          { quantity: 1, name: 'Pack 5' },
     ]
  }
]
```

So I got a filter input which has to filter the products by a coincidence on the name of the product or one or more origin's name.

For example, if I type "2" the result array must be:

```
products = [
  {
      name: 'Product 1',
      origins: [
          { quantity: 1, name: 'Pack 2' },
      ]
  },
  {
      name: 'Product 2',
      origins: [
          { quantity: 1, name: 'Pack 2' },
      ]
  }
]
```

Because the character "2" is in the name of origin of Product 1 and Product 2, also is present in the name "Product 2"
I tried many things to do this but the result array always modifies my original array when I put this in a pipe

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchtext">
<div *ngFor="let p of (saleProducts | filter : searchtext); let i = index">
    {{ p.name }}
    <div *ngIf="p.origins.length > 0">
        <div *ngFor="let o of p.origins">
            {{ o.name }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the best (simple and optimized) way to filter this using a pipe without modifying the original array?

Answer (score 0):

below a pipe implementation to with a default key `origins`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], searchName: string, key = 'origins'): any[] {
    const products = []
    value.forEach(product => {
      const matches = product[key].filter(({ name }) => name === searchName)
      if (matches.length) {
        products.push({ ...product, [key]: matches })
       }
    })
  
    return products
  }
}
```